# how to append a string to multiple files in linux

Tags: linux, csh

I have a folder containing multiple files such as

- file1
- myfile
- thisbogusfile
- anotherfile

I would like to append the string `.txt` at the end of every file. How can I do that with the command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to rename the files

```
foreach i (*)
   mv "$i" "$i.txt"
end
```

Comment: thanks but what would be the syntax in csh?

Comment: _foreach_ in _csh_, I edited my answer